# Flask-SQLAlchemy using STI: how to automatically substitute type field

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sti

I'm using **Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2** and have STI ([Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance)) configuration like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    info = db.Column(db.String(255))
    type = db.Column(db.String())

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class ItemA(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'a'
    }


class ItemB(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b'
    }


class ItemC(Item):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'c'
    }
```

And I want to query items of a particular kind. I can do it like this:

```
Item.query.filter_by(type='b').all()
```

Is there any chance to do it like the following?

```
ItemB.query.all()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should just work.

Comment: @univerio: unfortunately, it just returns all objects (not type=='b')

Comment: Using your configuration verbatim, the SQL rendered is `SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.info AS item_info, item.type AS item_type FROM item WHERE item.type IN (?)`.

Comment: I have different output for `ItemB.query.all()`

Comment: I don't know what to say except that [it works for me](https://repl.it/GFDD/0).

Comment: maybe it's because of flask-sqlalchemy... this code (https://gist.github.com/dizpers/4ff98ae9ed673132ce6a3a18946f05ea) gives me `SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.info AS item_info, item.type AS item_type 
FROM item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you are accidentally using joined table inheritance instead. flask-sqlalchemy automatically sets `__tablename__` for you. You need to explicitly set it to `None` if you want single table inheritance:

```
class ItemB(Item):
    __tablename__ = None
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b'
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, @univerio! :) You saved me from using hacky solution and spending more hours understanding why it's happening so. BTW, I've just posted the issue on Github (https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/481).

Comment: btw, do you know why this behaviour is happening and is there any way to disable it by default?

Comment: I also just noted that it's happening only with Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2 (2.1 is ok).

Comment: @dizpers Auto-setting `__tablename__` has been in flask-sqlalchemy since at least [0.12](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/1be46e07c7923b32b037e4f112292287573089b4) (6 years ago), if not earlier.

Comment: Gotcha. And I've just check with both 2.1 and 2.2 - `__tablename__` is set to `item`. And at the same time with 2.1 I got right query, with 2.2 - wrong one.

Comment: please check this https://repl.it/GFDD/2 - it works with raw SQLAlchemy and both `__table__` and `__tablename__` attributes values are not None. Seems like the problem is somewhere else. I'm posting updates at Github' issue page.